# Flat Laravel collection to tree

Tags: laravel, recursion, relationship

I have a Laravel collection of pages - each page has a "parent_id" property.  It resembles this.

```
"pages": [
    {

        "id": 1,
        "title": "Page 1 Level 1",
        "parent_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Page 2 Level 2",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Page 3 Level 3",
        "parent_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Page 4 Level 1",
        "parent_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Page 5 Level 2",
        "parent_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Page 6 Level 3",
        "parent_id": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Page 7 Level 1",
        "parent_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Page 8 Level 2",
        "parent_id": 7
    }
]
```

What I am trying to do is format the output so they are nested with the correct hierarchy. So for example:

```
"pages": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Page 1 Level 1",           
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Page 2 Level 2",           
                "parent_id": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "title": "Page 3 Level 3",           
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Page 4 Level 1",           
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "Page 5 Level 2",           
                "parent_id": 4,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "title": "Page 6 Level 3",           
                        "parent_id": 5,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Page 7 Level 1",           
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "title": "Page 8 Level 2",           
                "parent_id": 7,
                "children": []
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

The hierarchy can be any number of levels deep.  I have a nearly working version as shown below, but it does contain a bug. Whilst the various child objects are nesting with their parent, they also remain at the root level. So it looks like duplicates are actually placed in their nested positions.

Can anyone help me finish this off?

**PageController**

```php
$pages = Page::with('children')->get();
```

**Page**

```php
public function directChildren(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function children(): HasMany
{
    return $this->directChildren()->with('children'));
}
```

Comment: do you actually have that flat list?

Comment: @lagbox No. I'm ashamed to say that was careless typing. I have edited it now

Comment: so what is this first JSON you are showing then?

Comment: The first array is what I have to start with. (it had a typo in it before).  this is my flat list. It is actually a Laravel collection, but for convenience, I output it using the toArray() method.

Comment: you can turn that into a nested list pretty easily

Comment: That is what I am hoping, if you would be willing to share the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to nest these records:

```
$c = collect($data)->keyBy('id');

$result = $c->map(function ($item) use ($c) {
    if (! ($parent = $c->get($item->parent_id))) {
        return $item;
    }
    $parent->children[] = $item;
})->filter();
```

Answer (score 0):

All your parent elements seem to have `0` as `parent_id`. If this is the case, the following query should work:

```
$pages = Page::where('parent_id', 0)->with('children')->get();
```

You are basically selecting all parent pages first, then attaching its children tree. Without the `where`, you are selecting all pages, and attaching their children.

The other option is to define a parent relationship in the model, and select parents with children using something like `whereDoesntHave('parent'..)->with(children)`

Comment: This doesn't recurse. Anyone looking to query with recursion, using a nested set or adjacency list table architectures would be a good choices.

Comment: @JoelMellon yes you are right, somehow I have ignored the depth of the tree. Looks like I assumed the only bug was children being at the root of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @lagbox's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65945534/4468423):

```php
/**
 * Build a tree from a flat list of Pages.
 *
 * @param  Collection|Page[]  $pages
 * @return Collection|Page[]
 */
public static function asTree(Collection $pages)
{
    $pages = $pages->keyBy('id');

    return $pages->map(function (Page $page) use ($pages) {
            if (is_null($page->parent_id)) {  
                // or $page->parent_id === 0 if using 0 to indicate top-level pages
                return $page;
            }

            /** @var Page $parent */
            $parent = $pages->get($page->parent_id);

            // manually set the relation to avoid re-querying the database
            if (!$parent->relationLoaded('children')) {
                $parent->setRelation('children', collect()->push($page));
            } else {
                $parent->children->push($page);
            }
            
            return null;
        })
        ->filter()
        ->values();
}
```

I've also simplified the relationships to just a single `hasMany` referring to direct descendants only.

```php
// Page.php

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Page::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```